# mount dir not really exist

Tags: mount

I removed the snapd completely from my server, yet there is a directory still giving me trouble.
I can run:

```
cd /snap-snapd-16929
```

And it seems ok and when I'm running "df ." from inside I see:

> /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root [used size] [available size] /

It seems like the system see that snap dir is still mount on / but when I run:

```
umount /snap-snapd-16929
```

I get:

```
/snap-snapd-16929: not mounted.
```

Also, the snap dir doesn't show on df, lsblk or mount commands.

I can't restart the server now. Is there another way to refresh the mount list so the snap directory will be removed?

Thanks

Comment: `I removed the snapd completely from my server`, how? `yet there is a directory still giving me trouble`, in which way it is giving you trouble?  `It seems like the system see that snap dir is still mount on /` is a wrong conclusion, read `man df`. What are the contents of this folder? Please add the outpu of `ls -la /snap-snapd-16929` via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1497614/edit) to your question. `/snap-snapd-16929` is a very unusual filename, I don't think that it belongs to snapd installation at all. Have you tried to remove the folder?